# Python ArcPy - Print Layer with highest field value

Tags: python-3.6, arcpy

I have some python code that goes through layers in my ArcGIS project and prints out the layer names and their corresponding highest value within the field "SUM_USER_VisitCount". 
[Output Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7w9SI.png)

What I want the code to do is only print out the layer name and SUM_USER_VisitCount field value for the one layer with the absolute highest value.
[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XI4N8.png)

I have been unable to figure out how to achieve this and can't find anything online either. Can someone help me achieve my desired output?

Sorry if the code layout is a little weird. It got messed up when I pasted it into the "code sample"

Here is my code:

```
import arcpy
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import time


#Document Start Time in-order to calculate Run Time
time1 = time.clock()

#assign project and map frame
p = 
arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r'E:\arcGIS_Shared\Python\CumulativeHeatMaps.aprx')
m = p.listMaps('Map')[0]

Markets = [3000]


### Centers to loop through

CA_Centers = ['Castro', 'ColeValley', 'Excelsior', 'GlenPark', 
'LowerPacificHeights', 'Marina', 'NorthBeach', 'RedwoodCity', 'SanBruno', 
'DalyCity']   

for Market in Markets:
    print(Market)
    for CA_Center in CA_Centers:


        Layers = 
 m.listLayers("CumulativeSumWithin{0}_{1}_Jun2018".format(Market,CA_Center))

        fields = ['SUM_USER_VisitCount']


        for Layer in Layers:
            print(Layer)


            sqlClause = (None, 'ORDER BY ' + 'SUM_USER_VisitCount') # + 'DESC'

            with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(in_table = Layer, field_names = fields, 
            sql_clause = sqlClause) as searchCursor:
                print (max(searchCursor))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dictonary that stores the results from each query and then print out the highest one at the end.

```
results_dict = {}
for Market in Markets:
    print(Market)
    for CA_Center in CA_Centers:


        Layers = 
 m.listLayers("CumulativeSumWithin{0}_{1}_Jun2018".format(Market,CA_Center))

        fields = ['SUM_USER_VisitCount']


        for Layer in Layers:
            print(Layer)


            sqlClause = (None, 'ORDER BY ' + 'SUM_USER_VisitCount') # + 'DESC'

            with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(in_table = Layer, field_names = fields, 
            sql_clause = sqlClause) as searchCursor:
                print (max(searchCursor))
                results_dict[Layer] = max(searchCursor)

# get key for dictionary item with the highest value
highest_count_layer = max(results_dict, key=results_dict.get)
print(highest_count_layer)
print(results_dict[highest_count_layer])
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I tried your code, but it gives me the same print output as I was getting before

Comment: I may have misinterpreted your code due to the formatting. Check my edit to see if that is correct.

Comment: I don't really see a difference between your first and second versions, but I tried it and it still gives me the same results

Comment: I didn't edit the code in my answer, I edited the code in your question post. I wanted to make sure my edits of your code were correct.

Comment: Ok we are getting close. This time it printed out `Layer (47.0)`, which is the lowest value and missing the actual layer name

Comment: Can you add a print statement at the end that print out the entire results_dict (i.e. `print(results_dict)` and paste the output here? I want to see what that dict look like at the end. It's difficult to debug this without knowing what the data or output looks like.

Comment: this is the results I get when using print(results_dict). `{'Layer': (47.0,)}`. It seems to me like the dictionary entrees may be overwriting each other

Comment: Yes they were overwriting each other, I had `results_dict['Layer']` instead of `results_dict[Layer]`. Test it now.